# implement favorite button in listview android studio

Tags: android, listview

I am implementing favorite button in ListView trying from the last five days. I have created a ListView which gets the current textview text and saves it in the ArrayList (names) and if the data is already present then deletes it, works perfectly but when I close the app the ArrayList gets empty i wants to save the array list in  preferences.

array declaration:

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

Below is the code

```
favoritebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v) {
        if (!names.contains(textView_name.getText())){
            names.add((String) textView_name.getText());

            for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(names.get(i));
                favoritebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_checked);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(textView_name.getText() + "   is already present in the Array at index " + names.indexOf(textView_name.getText()));
            int currentIndex = names.indexOf(textView_name.getText());
            names.remove(currentIndex);
            for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(names.get(i));
                favoritebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_off);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to retrieve and store data like below:

```
private ArrayList<String> names;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String favoriteItems = sharedPreferences.getString("FAVORITE_ITEMS", "");

if(favoriteItems.isEmpty())
    names = new ArrayList<>();
else
    names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(favoriteItems.split(","));  //Update like this


favoritebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v) {
        if (!names.contains(textView_name.getText())){
            names.add((String) textView_name.getText());

            for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(names.get(i));
                favoritebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_checked);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(textView_name.getText() + "   is already present in the Array at index " + names.indexOf(textView_name.getText()));
            int currentIndex = names.indexOf(textView_name.getText());
            names.remove(currentIndex);
            for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(names.get(i));
                favoritebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_off);
            }
        }

        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("FAVORITE_ITEMS", TextUtils.join(",", names)).apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: for the first time the app runs and after saving multiples items and then again running it the app crashes @Md. Assaduzzaman

Comment: Add the stack trace then

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.apple.androidp3/com.example.apple.androidp3.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: Check my updated answer. Use `names = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(favoriteItems.split(",")); ` rather than casting

Comment: @sajjadahmad, Is it ok now?

Comment: The problem solved but  R.drawable.fav_checked and fav_unchecked doesn't remains stable when i scroll up or down the fav_image disappears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203834/discussion-between-sajjad-ahmad-and-md-asaduzzaman).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to save that list in preferences after each update you can use Gson lib for that which convert array list to JsonArray and JsonArray to Arraylist which will help to you...

```
String str = fetchFromPref();
ArrayList<String> names = covertToArrayListFromJSOnString(str);

favoritebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v) {
        if (!names.contains(textView_name.getText())){
            names.add((String) textView_name.getText());

            for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(names.get(i));
                favoritebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fav_checked);
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(textView_name.getText() + "   is already present in the Array at index " + names.indexOf(textView_name.getText()));
            int currentIndex = names.indexOf(textView_name.getText());
            names.remove(currentIndex);
            for (int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(names.get(i));
                favoritebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_off);
            }

        }
        String str = convertArrayListToJson(names).toString();
        saveToPrefrences(str);
    }
});
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol method fetchFromPref()
cannot find symbol method covertToArrayListFromJSOnString(String)
 cannot find symbol method convertArrayListToJson(ArrayList<String>)
error: cannot find symbol method saveToPrefrences(String)